# Match a string against a route

Tags: routes, match, laravel-5

Is there a method in Laravel 5 to which I give the following string `projects/1/files` and it tells me if it matches the route `projects/{id}/files`?

Comment: Can you please give more code examples and tell in more details what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use route patterns:

```
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+'); //matches 0-9 
Route::get('projects/{id}/files', 'controller@method');
```

Another example:

```
Route::pattern('slug', '[a-z0-9-]+'); //matches a-z, 0-9 and '-'
Route::get('projects/{slug}/files', 'controller@method');
```

Comment: I don't want to declare the route, but to test the **if the string matches** that route in order to display the active link

Comment: I cannot properly understand you.

Comment: I'm looking for a function that I can call like this `match('projects/1/files', 'projects/{id}/files')` and it must return **true**